# Search by sub-collections mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Query

```
db.user.save({'user_id':1603,'email':'test@test.com','rel':[{'fid':1604,'s':0},{'fid':1605,'s':1},{'fid':1606,'s':2}]})
```

Creates a collection of `USER`, writes her a user who has a `user_id`, `email`, and a sub-collection REL.

Inside the sub-collection are a pair of REL FID (Friend ID) and S (Status of friendship).

For example,

0 - Sent friend request
1 - Friends
2 - Denied friendship
etc.

In other words, a sub-collection REL user ID 1603 is information about how, with whom he is friendly, and the status of friendship.

Problem. There is a user with the ID 1606 and we need to find out what it is dealing with a user ID 1603.

To do this, first find a user with ID 1603, get it REL

```
db.user.findOne({'user_id': 1603}, {'rel': true})
```

Search for the FID c value of 1606, on a sub-collection of REL, found the user with the ID 1603.

If such an FID is found, return to S. I.e. User friendly status in 1606 and 1603.

This is where the problem occurs. If podskazhesh will primnogo grateful.

Comment: at least try and use some formatting so we can read your commands! also what does "If podskazhesh will primnogo grateful" mean? I am guessing it is in a non-English language but this is an English language site and you should try to translate first.

Comment: I don't see any sub-colelction "REL" with this, just a REL key inside the document?

Answer (score 2):

Good news there may be a better query.

```
db.user.findOne({'user_id': 1603}, {'rel.fid': 1606})
```

If that works, then 1606 is a friend of 1603.

**Side note**

MongoDB does not support the notion of "sub-collections". A `database` contains `collections` which contain `documents`. There's no notion of "sub-collection" there.

In your case, you have a `document` that contains a `value` that is an `array` type. But MongoDB does not have any type of join syntax. So it's just an "array of references", it's not really a "sub-collection" there is no referential integrity here.

Comment: Mongoose framework support creating subcollections. It is documented in their site (mongoosejs.com). But all the information, given on that page shows only retrieveing an array element. But they said that sub-collection element will have it's OWN ObjectID.

Comment: If they have such a feature, it's their own feature & naming, but it's not a part of MongoDB. Mongoose does give you a way to abstract joins, but under the hood they have to do multiple queries to make such joins happen.